# how can i clear the previous dependency check in debian terminal

Tags: linux, bash, debian, terminal, apt

i was trying to install few tools under my debian-linux but whenever i tried to install new one with dependency it remembers the old one

Background :

Yesterday i tried to install master pdf editor with the following command

```
apt-get -f install masterpdfeditor
```

Before the machine download and install dependency i closed the terminal and shutdown the machine

Now today i tried to install ssh client another new package

with the command :

```
apt-get install chkconfig

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

 state information... Done
```

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:   master-pdf-editor3:i386 : Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4.6.4) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4.6.4) but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4.8.4) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

As per my understanding yesterday the terminal was trying to install masterpdf which was quited yesterday by mine

Additionally chkconfig was configuration check tool whereas masterpdf was pdf editor both can't have same dependency's.

My questions were few :
how can i clear master pdf and install chkconfig,in other words how can i clear previous install/dependency check at the machine to install new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get -f install
```

i used it and corrected my dependency checks ,The command install old dependency check and allowed me to install the new one